# Dropbox Core and Sync APIs together in Android App

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Is it possible to use both the Core and Sync Api in one Android app?

Comment: I would suggest you don't do this, because the Sync API is deprecated. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/android

Comment: Definitely not for new projects! We have a lot of old code written using the sync API and now I wrote some new functions using the core API. This is just an approach for a slow migration.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use them together. It's a 2 part setup.

**Removing Project errors:**

1. Add jar files both SDKs to your project
2. Now open Dropbox Core SDK jar file and remove the `client2.Auth` classes - anything that's causing a namespace collision. You will see errors until this is fixed

**Authenticating the SDKs:**

3. Setup dropbox linking for the Sync SDK - there are many docs on this
4. Get the oAuth credentials from Sync SDK for your Core SDK using:

   ```
     AppKeyPair appKeyPair = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
     AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeyPair);
     session.setOAuth2AccessToken(getTokenFromSyncAPI());
     session.finishAuthentication();
   ```

And finally, the missing method:

```
String getTokenFromSyncAPI() {
    String token = null;

    String allTokens = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("dropbox-credentials",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("accounts", null);

    try {
        JSONArray jsonAccounts = new JSONArray(allTokens);
        if (jsonAccounts.length() > 0) {
            String tmpToken = null;
            tmpToken = jsonAccounts.getJSONObject(0).getString("userToken");

            // We take only oAuth2 tokens
            if (tmpToken.startsWith("|oa2|"))
                token = tmpToken.substring(5);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return token;
}
```

Method courtesy : https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/05/migrating-sync-sdk-access-tokens-to-core-sdk/

PS : The method shown at the link has a bug. `substring(6)` instead of `5`